# Caldroid calendar unparsable date exception

Tags: java, date, oop, caldroid

I am trying to get the selected date in dd/MM/yyyy format from Caldroid calendar but when I am parsing the date it will throw an following error.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu May 04 00:00:00 GMT 2017" (at offset 0)
```

**Below is my code:-**

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
final CaldroidListener caldroidListener = new CaldroidListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
                try {
                    String dateParse = date.toString();
                    Log.d("Date before parse: ",date.toString());
                    sdf.parse(dateParse);
                    Log.d("Date after parse: ",dateParse);
                    eventDate.setText(dateParse);
                }catch(ParseException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: I assume it's because `Thu May 04 00:00:00 GMT 2017` doesn't match the format `dd/MM/yyyy`....

Comment: But I am parsing the original date format to dd/MM/yyyy format.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up `parse` and `format`. You want to format the input date with your `SimpleDateFormat` and then set the resulting string in the `.setText` ?

Comment: Oh yeah why are you even calling `date.toString()`? Just call `sdf.format(date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want your code to do (without the logging):

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
final CaldroidListener caldroidListener = new CaldroidListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
                eventDate.setText(sdf.format(date));

            }
        };
```

You use `SimpleDateFormat#format` to get a formatted string out of your `Date`.

Comment: Thanks @Robin Topper for answer it works fine, I am just forget about format method. And also thanks others for comment and advise.